# Building a jar file from a gradle dependency

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, timber

I need to make dex file from my android project. First, i need to compile my classes to jar. But i need dependencies in jar. otherwise, i'll get about 300 errors because of unknown methods. I need Timber in jar. but i can't find it in the internet. I  searched a lot, but no luck. This is the link to the source code in github.
https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber

How do i build a jar from this gradle project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add gradle library to your project, you need to add `implementation "package-group:package-name:package-version"` to your build.gradle.

For Timber, you would do `implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1"`.

If you want to compile your project, with its dependencies into a jar, then you want to look up "fat jars". Gradle [Shadowjar](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/getting-started/#default-java-groovy-tasks) is a plugin that does this.